# Ошибка вызова ссылки на функцию

Tags: javascript

Почему следующий код не валидный?

```
var t = Object.prototype.toString.call;
console.log(t); //==> function call()
t();            //==> Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function
```

Почему если *t* это функция, то при попытке ее вызвать выдается сообщение, что *t* это не функция?!

P.S. Я знаю, что правильно брать ссылку на call ф-ции toString надо так: `Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.toString)`. Мне просто непонятно сама суть проблемы: если t это функция, то почему при попытке ее вызвать выдается сообщение, что t это не функция?

P.S.S. Проверено в Chrome и IE11
[image: Chrome console]

Comment: А что за движок JS? Мозилловский например говорит совсем другую ошибку.

Comment: Добавил эту инф-цию в топик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какую-то ясность внес Microsoft Edge. Если своими словами, то он говорит, мол f я вызываю, но this внутри call не является ф-цией (что при вызове f() в принципе является правдой). Просто Хром выдает вообще какое-то невменяемое сообщение из коотрого можно сделать вывод, что типа f не можно вызвать вообще (что меня собственно и смутило)

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так?

```
var t =function(){
return Object.prototype.toString.call;
}

t();
```

Comment: И что это меняет? Мне не надо получить ссылку на call, я хочу произвести вызов call через обычную ссылку на нее. Вот странно, почему Object.prototype.toString.call() работает, а (var f = Object.prototype.toString.call)() не работает

Comment: Call внутренний метод для объекта Function.

var f = function () {};
f.calls =  Object.prototype.toString.call;
f.calls();

Comment: Виталий, не могли бы Вы разъяснить почему f.calls() происходит корректно? Причина как я понимаю это потому что calls является полем ф-ции. Но какое это имеет отношение к вызову ф-ции? Ошибка ведь происходит не внутри ф-ции call, типа ее нельзя вызывать с объектами 'не ф-ция' (typeof this !== 'function'), а ошибку бросает сам движок, все равно что если б мы попробовали сделать ({})(). Вообщем пока что ситуация для меня не прояснилась, буду признателен за объяснение

Comment: а чего вы без скобок вызываете? Object.prototype.toString.call()